# Dealing with LINQ to Objects when object not found

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am using Linq statement as per below to find student name by its ID. It works fine. However there are cases where there is no student with given ID. In those cases an error is thrown "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

How to efficiently deal with this problem?

```
Dim Name As String = Students.FirstOrDefault(Function(Student) Student.ID = "NO00007").Name
```

Comment: Get the object first, then check if it is null or not. if not, then get the .Name otherwise deal with it appropriately

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency. There's no performance issue here. Just check the return value for null before you use it.

Comment: Is there any chance to be more than one student with the same id?

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering if there is more elegant and shorter way to do that than getting the object first and checking if it is null.

Comment: @MaciejLos no, ID is unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are satisfied with `Name` being null if there is no matching student, you can use the null conditional operator for member access:

```
Dim Name As String = Students.FirstOrDefault(Function(Student) Student.ID = "NO00007")?.Name
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that this feature was added in VB.NET 14, as of VS 2015, the VB equivalent of C#6.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As usually answer is "it depend" - it depend on how you will use result you will get

If you want get some "default"/empty string instead of name when collection doesn't contain item

```
Dim result = Students.Where(Function(student) student.ID = "NO00007").
                      Select(Function(student) student.Name).
                      DefaultIfEmpty(String.Empty).
                      First()
```

Almost same approach if you want to get some "empty" object instead of `null`

```
Dim resultStudent = Students.Where(Function(student) student.ID = "NO00007").
                             DefaultIfEmpty(New Student With { .Name = "empty" }).
                             First()
```

From performance point of view approach above are same as `FirstOrDefault` - but provide little bid better readability(subjective of course)